# Typescript does not understand undefined return type when used with optional chaining

Tags: typescript, undefined, optional-chaining

I have a very simple code:

```
const foo = (state: RootState): MyData => undefined;
```

This gives an error:

> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'MyData'.

Which is quite reasonable since my type `MyData` does not allow undefined.

But if I now write this:

```
const foo = (state: RootState): MyData => state.data?.myData;
```

Then it compiles without troubles. I don't understand what is going on here since if `state.data` is undefined then it should be really returning undefined and should be quite obvious to the compiler.

Am I missing something here?

P.S. This is the minimal example for types:

```
type State = {
  data: {
    myData: MyData;
  };
}

type MyData = {

}
```

Comment: Please show us (minimal versions of) the definitions of `RootState` and `MyData`. If I make [reasonable guesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHt1gMpjpZAbwChkzkATfOAfgC4jTzmBbATwBFqGBZT6gNxMyAX2JjioSLEQo+XPI2YAjOFAYBnMFFABzIRIToQW5DEwBGZAF5kACi34IDDFlxOAlL36LrAPmQAVxAKCBhQCAohYiMTMDNMACYbe0dIF0wcPEgvZHlqGwC0iAA6KjwaEvYFOAEgA), TypeScript complains about both functions.

Comment: Did not think it is important, let me add it

Comment: When i make a reasonable guess at the types, typescript complains as you're asking it to (https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=62#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8Aicx2QbwChlkALCAGwoHsAuZAcgHdqoKATBwgX0NEliIUAJWrUwAZVyQCxZOxxwA-PSIkSAWyyKVabbjm9ehBNRABnMMhhjkAXmQAKSzgj1R4qa4CU9DNlx7AD5kF0gAOgVcJXCtALgAbiA). Perhaps your type definitions have data and myData as never being undefined, so typescript deduces that the optional chaining is never going to matter?

Comment: It seems you are right! Did not think about it, typescript outsmarted me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like `data` is not optional in `RootState`.

TypeScript complains about both of these functions, since — as you say — `MyData | undefined` is not assignable to `MyData`:

```
interface RootState {
    data?: {
        myData: MyData;
    }
}

interface MyData {
    bar: string;
}

const foo1 = (state: RootState): MyData => undefined;

const foo2 = (state: RootState): MyData => state.data?.myData;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHt1gMpjpZAbwChkzkATfOAfgC4jTzmBbATwBFqGBZT6gNxMyAX2JjioSLEQo+XPI2YAjOFAYBnMFFABzIRIToQW5DEwBGZAF5kACi34IDDFlxOAlL36LrAPmQAVxAKCBhQCAohYiMTMDNMACYbe0dIF0wcPEgvZHlqGwC0iAA6KjwaEvYFOAEgA)

But it's happy if `data` in `RootState` is not optional:

```
interface RootState {
    data: {
        myData: MyData;
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHt1gMpjpZAbwChkzkATfOALiNPMYFsBPAEWroFl3qBuBmQC+xEcVCRYiFDw556jAEZwodAM5gooAOYCxCdCA3IYmAIzIAvMgAUG-BDoYsuBwEpuveZYB8yAK4gFBAwoBAUAsQGRmAmmABMVrb2kE6YOHiQHsiy1FZ+KRAAdFR4APxFrHJwfEA)

It's happy because the TypeScript compiler knows that the `?` there is non-functional, because `data` isn't optional, can't have the value `undefined`, and can't have the value `null`. So `state.data.myData` and `state.data?.myData` do exactly the same thing: yield a value of type `MyData`.

Comment: Thanks, that seems very correct, though I wish typescript did a warning that using optional chaining is not allowed, or rather an error like in C# e.g.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik if you're using typescript-eslint, they have a rule which will alert you if you use optional chaining when it isn't necessary: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unnecessary-condition.md

Comment: I do, thanks, will turn it on, it's default value is false